# 2020 Macbook Pro M1 screen flickering

Tags: apple-m1, retina

I found out that my M1 Mac starts to flicker screen in PyCharm, CLion, or UTM (The only soft for VM's on M1 Macs). Is this a problem of M1 being completely different from other chips, or I have to return my Mac in shop?

I tried rebooting the Mac, of course. Also, I checked if my IDEs are downloaded with correct architecture. Nothing helped.

Comment: Same for me. I use IntelliJ and PyCharm, I only have the issue with PyCharm

Answer (score 1):

In my case I switched off `automatically adjust brightness` in `Display settings` the flickering stopped.